# Unclearance in mutual exclusion example

Tags: process, flags, critical-section, mutual-exclusion

I have read several examples about mutual exclusions, and I can understand the run of most of them except the following example handed to me:

```
boolean[] flag = new boolean[2];
```

[image]

one while-condition is depending on the flag[n] state of the other process.
So in order to for example have `P1` heading into it's critical section both `flag[0]` and `flag[1]` need to be set `true`.

According to my interpertation the entire run will have to look like this:

```
P1 - > flag[1] = true
while(flag[0])            // flag[0] is still state-undeclared
P2  -> flag[0]  = true    // so P0 must set it true(?)
critic1(); 
while(flag[1]) 
critic2();
```

Though this can't be correct since with `flag[0]` and `flag[1]` set to true both processes pass the `while(flag[n])` condition and a race-condition could still occur. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: feel free for any queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration and definition

```
boolean[] flag = new boolean[2];
```

looks like java, and in java the boolean array is filled with false as default values.

> So in order to for example have P1 heading into it's critical section
>   both flag[0] and flag[1] need to be set true.

**No that is not the case**, for **P1** to be heading into the `Critical Section`, only thing is that following statement of **P0** must not be executed before **P1** enters the `Critical Section`.

```
flag[0] = true;
```

and since by default `flag[0] = false`, the loop condition `while(flag[0])` will be false and **P1** will enter the critical section.

If processes **P0** and **P1** are scheduled in such a way that the following statements are executed for both processes **before the corresponding next statement**:

```
flag[0] = true; and flag[1] = true;
```

**In such case deadlock will occur.**